# Change UIImage depending on transaction status

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

```
import UIKit

class TransactionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UIImageView!

let transactionStatus = DataManager.shared.transactionController.transactions



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    Status()
    
}

func Status() {
    let arr = transactionStatus.compactMap { $0 }
    for i in 0..<arr.count {
        if arr[i].status == "returned" {
            status.image = UIImage(assetIdentifier: .statusReturned)
        } else if arr[i].status == "pending" {
            status.image = UIImage(assetIdentifier: .statusPending)
        } else if arr[i].status == "cleared" {
            status.image = UIImage(assetIdentifier: .statusCleared)
        } else {
            print("\(String(describing: arr[i].status)) + no matched ")
        }
}


extension UIImage {
  enum AssetIdentifier: String {
      // Status image names
      case statusPending, statusCleared, statusReturned
    }

    convenience init!(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier) {
      self.init(named: assetIdentifier.rawValue)
  }
}
```

Hi, so I have a question, I wrote a function that changes the status icon of the transaction depending on the status(String i receive from db), but it changes the icons of all transactions at once depending on the status of the last transaction received, such as if the last status was "returned" then everyone will have a status icon returned

I wonder why it works like that, so the question is how to make each icon change separately and not all at once
[what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6fKx.png)
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uRz1.png)
Please pay attention to icons on the left side of the screen

Comment: You have a`for` loop in a tableview cell. This doesn't make sense. It sets the image based on the last element of the array. A table view cell is only displaying one element of your data. Your table view data source (typically the view controller) should configure the cell appropriately for a single data element in `cellForRow(at:)`

Comment: You can use `arr.last?.status`, no need for a loop.

Comment: That won't help. This code is in the wrong place. The cell doesn't know which row it is. The code needs to be in `cellForRow(at:)` where the `indexPath.row` can be used to access the array.